# MVC4 Razor View IntelliSense Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Explanation:

The Views are generated with the default scaffolding type : "MVC controller with read/write actions and view, using Entity Framework"

**I would like to know why the *"DOES NOT SHOW UP INTELLISENSE"* don't show the intellisense after *chaning the strongly* typed Model, even if you chang it back.**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName) <- DOES NOT SHOW UP (INTELLISENSE)unless strongly typed against a NON-Collection must remove lambda expression
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)<- DOES NOT SHOW UP (INTELLISENSE) unless strongly typed against a NON-Collection must remove lambda expression
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.)<- DOES NOT SHOW UP (INTELLISENSE)unless strongly typed against a NON-Collection must remove lambda expression
    </th>
    <th>

    </th>
</tr>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)<- SHOWS INTELLISENSE
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)<- SHOWS INTELLISENSE
    </td>
    <td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda weirds me out too, but since it's an `IEnumerable` you'd only have things like `Count()` available at that time.

However, you can use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().UserName)` so now you have an instance with intellisense.

Side Note: I have seen the out-of-the-box MVC scaffolds get away with using an instance property (despite it being an `IEnumerable`) and my only guess is there is an overload that works this way, or there are MVC gnomes wiring it up. Either way it's probably better you use `FirstOrDefault()`. As a shortcut, I tend to declare a single element at the top of my page and use that for the purpose of headings. e.g.

```
@model IEnumerable<Foo>
@{
 @header = Model.FirstOrDefault();
}

@* ... *@
  <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => header.FirstName)</th>
  <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => header.LastName)</th>
@* ... *@
```

Comment: Why Default? When returning null the header.FirstName will throw an exception!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show it because now you have multiple user profiles in your collection.

```
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain a little bit more? I used the CopyUserProfiles as an example. ( in the above example code )

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle Show what you pass to the view in your controller. Do you pass one user or collection of users?

Comment: @Steve There you go, context, model,view,controller code up see if you can find out now whats going wrong?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle I was right, you return list of users, not one user so you need to loop through them to show their values.